# Fisher information for handwashing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

I have two sets of data: the bacteria count on people's hands (n=1e4) without washing `x`.  They then washed their hands and the count was made again `xwash`.  What is the best way to estimate the reduction between these groups?

Is there a formalised/sophisticated comparison test or am I reduced to hypothesis testing?  What are my options?

Best regards.

(PS. other parameters may alter hand washing effectiveness)

Comment: The question title mentions Fisher information, but the actual question doesn't. If your question really is about Fisher information, could you please clarify how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you've kept records of which measurement that belongs to which individual, so that you have a pair of observations $(x_i,xwash_i)$ for each person, you can construct a variable $y_i=x_i-xwash_i$ and perform a one-sample t-test using your $n$ differences $y_1,\ldots,y_n$. Unless you have heavily rounded data, that should work well. You don't need more sophistication than that!

Comment: Would that not just give me the p-value for rejecting the null hypothesis of similar variance rather than a reduction of bacteria?  The data is far from normal, so using Chi$^2$ test for GOF wouldn't be the right way would it? What do you think?

Comment: Wouldn't you say that $x-xwash$, i.e. the difference in bacteria counts, is the natural way of measuring the reduction of bacteria? The t-test is used to compare means, not variances. I assumed that you wish to study the mean reduction and not differences in variance. For most non-normal data, the t-test usually works quite well for sample sizes as large as $n=10000$. If you give us some further information about your data (such as a few observations) we might be able to give a better answer to whether or not the t-test can be used.

Comment: I am interested in computing the sensitivity of the bacteria count to altering parameters such as how often the hands are washed, or how well. In other words a sensitivity analysis. You are right in your insight, the reduction in bacteria is usually done by some form of $log(x-x_wash)$. But I'd like to quantify, not just correlate how effective certain methods of reduction are. Ie more formally than just the log reduction. Does that clarify my question a little bit?